# Create a executable patch for upgrading my application

Tags: java, jar, upgrade, patch

I want to create a executable jar patch for my application and give it to my clients for updating the previous version of application.

I do not want the existing application on client systems is removed manualy and then installed the new version.

The new version has the following changes:

1. Some tables of database has changed.(new columns, new tables)
2. Some new libraries were added to Classpath of the application.
3. Some new classes were added.

My database is Postgresql.

How can i make an executable jar file for upgrading my application to new version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to upgrade your application is to write a shell-script and patch changes in it. if the main jar file of your app is also changed you can replace it with new one. if you do not want to transport not-changed parts of the jar, you can use a `unzip/add-changes/zip` sequence to upgrade the jar file. tools like `zcmp` or `zdiff` may be helpful.